# how to make multiple connection to database using php and mysql

Tags: php

I have an associative array contain multiple database configuration and I want to make all connection to database in this array

```
$dbconfig = array(
    'servername' => array('localhost','localhost'),
    'username' => array('root1','root2'),
    'password' => array('p1','p2'),
    'db' => array('db1','db2'),
);
 $conn = mysqli_connect($dbconfig['servername'], $dbconfig['username'], $dbconfig['password'], $dbconfig['db']);
```

Comment: And what's your question about this? The code you've shared does not connect to any database at all

Comment: @NicoHaase I tried to make connection but I think it need a for loop to iterate over them

Comment: And what keeps you from using a loop?

Comment: @NicoHaase I don't know how to delay with it

Comment: The two databases seem to in the same mysql instance. In this case one connection can cover both databases, provided the same mysql user has access to both databases. Otherwise, yes you need to create multiple connections in a loop with different php variables holding each connection

Comment: @Shadow yes right I need multiple connection in a loop with different php variables holding each connection  but I am trying to find solution to code that

Comment: Where did you get stuck with writing a loop?

Comment: @Shadow I don't know how use it with this array

Comment: Could be simpler if you stored the settings for a connection in a single array as opposed to in several arrays as you do now. But all you need is a for loop starting from 0 and use the loop variable as index for the arrays.

Comment: @Shadow yes we can change it no problem

Comment: "how to delay with it" - what does that mean? Your question does not contain any information about any delay. Please edit it to contain all relevant information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should transpose your array structure to this:

```
<?php
$dbconfig = array(
    array(
        'servername' => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'root1',
        'password' => 'p1',
        'db' => 'db1'
    ),
    array(
        'servername' => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'root2',
        'password' => 'p2',
        'db' => 'db2'
    )
);
```

Because this allows you to more easily iterate through the array:

```
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($dbconfig); $i++) {
    $conn[$i] = mysqli_connect($dbconfig[$i]['servername'], $dbconfig[$i]['username'], $dbconfig[$i]['password'], $dbconfig[$i]['db']);
}
```